# HTML CSS: Border around multiple DIV from different rows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a border around the search panel.

There are 3 rows here.
I dont want border around the 3 buttons in the last row at right corner.

My current UI looks like this :

[image]

I want to apply border in following way:

[image]

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="fromDate">Show Requests From:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="fromDate" type="text" style="width:120px; display:inline" value='@ViewBag.fromDate' autocomplete="off" />
                <label for="toDate">To</label>
                <input class="form-control input-sm " id="toDate" type="text" style="width:120px; display:inline" value='@ViewBag.toDate' autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
            <div class="">
                <label>OR</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="custNameAccNumSearchBox">Customer Name / Account Number:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control input-sm " id="custNameAccNumSearchBox" type="text" style="width:175px; display:inline"  autocomplete="off" />
                <input type="button" id="search" name="search" value="Search" style="margin-bottom:0px" class="btn btn-primary small-padding col-md-offset-1" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Button", "", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary small-padding" })
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Button", "", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary small-padding" })
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
                <p>
                    <button type="button" disabled class="btn btn-primary small-padding disabled_lc">Button</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Wrap all of them in another div and put the border on that

Answer (score 1):

Considering limited code and the as per requirement, you can do something like this:

> You can add another `selector` for the block for which you need a border.

```css
#forBorder {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="forBorder">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="fromDate">Show Requests From:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" id="fromDate" type="text" style="width:120px; display:inline" value='@ViewBag.fromDate' autocomplete="off" />
      <label for="toDate">To</label>
      <input class="form-control input-sm " id="toDate" type="text" style="width:120px; display:inline" value='@ViewBag.toDate' autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <div class="">
      <label>OR</label>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="custNameAccNumSearchBox">Customer Name / Account Number:</label>




      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control input-sm " id="custNameAccNumSearchBox" type="text" style="width:175px; display:inline" autocomplete="off" />
        <input type="button" id="search" name="search" value="Search" style="margin-bottom:0px" class="btn btn-primary small-padding col-md-offset-1" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-2">
  <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Button", "", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary small-padding" })
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
  <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Button", "", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary small-padding" })
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
  <p>
    <button type="button" disabled class="btn btn-primary small-padding disabled_lc">Button</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

without changing the HTML, you can try this CSS.
But the solution already mentioned to add a DIV container seems better to me.

```
.row:nth-child(1) {
   border:solid 1px blue;
   border-bottom:none;
}
.row:nth-child(2) {
   border-left:solid 1px blue;
   border-right:solid 1px blue;
}
.row:nth-child(3) {
   border:solid 1px blue;
   border-top:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can be using 
like this

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
 </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--this will be inseted here --> 
    <div style="border-style: solid;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="fromDate">Show Requests From:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="fromDate" type="text" style="width:120px; display:inline" value='@ViewBag.fromDate' autocomplete="off" />
            <label for="toDate">To</label>
            <input class="form-control input-sm " id="toDate" type="text" style="width:120px; display:inline" value='@ViewBag.toDate' autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        <div class="">
            <label>OR</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="custNameAccNumSearchBox">Customer Name / Account Number:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control input-sm " id="custNameAccNumSearchBox" type="text" style="width:175px; display:inline"  autocomplete="off" />
            <input type="button" id="search" name="search" value="Search" style="margin-bottom:0px" class="btn btn-primary small-padding col-md-offset-1" />
        </div>
    </div> <!-- And end here -->   
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-2">
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Button", "", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary small-padding" })
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Button", "", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary small-padding" })
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
            <p>
                <button type="button" disabled class="btn btn-primary small-padding disabled_lc">Button</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

just need to make a super div which will cover all those divs on which you want to put border